# Trouble installing PostgreSQL 9 64bit on fairly fresh Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Tags: windows, postgresql

The installation proceeds most of the way without any issues.

At the end, I get an alert saying that there was a "Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed."

The `install-postgresql.log` file contains:

```
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "postgres" "postgres" "****" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1" "C:\postgresql-data" 5432 "DEFAULT"
Script exit code: 1

Script output:
 WScript.Shell Initialized...
Scripting.FileSystemObject initialized...

WScript.Network initialized...
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can read the path C: (using icacls) to Krystian:
    Executing batch file 'rad8D950.bat'...
    Invalid parameter "Krystian:(RX)(NP)"

Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can read the path C:\postgresql-data (using icacls) to Krystian:
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:6.1
    MajorVersion:6
Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using icacls) to  Krystian:
Failed to ensure the data directory is accessible (C:\postgresql-data)
Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb
```

I tried the following variants:
 - installing 64bit PostgreSQL on Windows 7 64 bit
 - installing 32bit PostgreSQL on Windows 7 64 bit
 - creating a directory `C:\postgresql-data\` and using it as the data dir to avoid storing data in Program Files

None of these options have worked. I cannot get it to install properly. I have a fairly new install of Windows 7 (less than 24 hours old).

I have seen post regarding this issue in many forums when I googled it. However, no resolutions worked for me.

Has anyone experienced this exact issue and been able to resolve it? If so, please share your wonderful answer.

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/363771/troubles-installing-postgresql-9-64bit-on-windows-7-64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an acceptable solution:

http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1891.page

Please see the answer by `Sampath+Rachakonda`.

The short answer is that you cannot install Postgresql to a directory inside of `Program Files`.

The solution is to do an install to, say `C:\Postgresql\`. After the install, you will get the same error. After the install, empty out the `C:\Postgresql\` and set its permission to allow the `postgres` user full control (or give it full ownership). Do the install again. All should work well.